# associate existing classes with storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm new to iOS developing so please forgive me if the question is too naive. I'm writing an app based on some other's code, and the author the original code generated all UI elements programmatically (no xib/nib files). I want to modify the interface and go with the storyboard approach, so I have to associate the existing classes with the new view controllers I have on storyboard. I changed the "Custom Class" to the existing class via interface builder. But I keep getting this error:

2014-03-12 22:49:56.187 Reader[9064:a0b] The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.

Any thoughts? I hope I don't have to start over from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. Go to your app delegate file, usually named something like XXAppDelegate.h, then declare the property in the app delegate class like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

Comment: After doing that, will all code generated UI elements appear on the storyboard? @JJC

Comment: As long as you've properly hooked up the view controllers in your code to the ones in the storyboard, and you're adding your UI elements correctly, it should work.

Comment: I've added the property but those UI elements still does not appear on the storyboard. Is it because those UI elements won't automatically transfer to storyboard at all? @JJC

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about what you're asking but there isn't a way to transfer something created programmatically to the storyboard. You have to set up the storyboard views yourself, and hook them up to objects in your source code.

Comment: I mean all the UI elements are hard-coded in the source code. So that said, I have to redraw all the elements on storyboard and hook them up to the elements in the code?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Unfortunately, there is no automated process to do this.

Comment: After that, do I have to remove the original code that places the UI elements and retain only the properties representing those UI elements? Will there be any conflicts? Sorry about asking so many questions!

Comment: I don't know enough about your code to say so. If your code explicitly adds elements to your view controllers when loading from a storyboard, and you don't want that, then of course you'll have to remove the code. In any case, it's good practice to remove code cruft whenever you can.